# Navigate between divs with the same classname in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a plugin that allow to add popup to images,i want that when i click on a popup i can navigate between all popups with previous and next buttons.

Here is my element when its showen :

```
<div class="imp-tooltip.imp-tooltip-visible" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 20px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)"></div>
```

and i tried this :

```
<nav>
    <button id="down" ></button>
    <button id="up" ></button>
</nav>


var $currentElement = $(".imp-tooltip imp-tooltip-visible").first();

$("#down").click(function () {
    var $nextElement = $currentElement.next('.imp-tooltip');
    if($nextElement.length) {

        $currentElement = $nextElement;
        $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
            scrollTop: $nextElement.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
    return false;
});

$("#up").click(function () {
    var $prevElement = $currentElement.prev('.imp-tooltip');
    if($prevElement.length) {
        $currentElement = $prevElement;
        $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
            scrollTop: $prevElement.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
    return false;  
});
```

Comment: This selector is invalid: `$(".imp-tooltip imp-tooltip-visible")`. It should be: `$(".imp-tooltip.imp-tooltip-visible")`. Or just `$(".imp-tooltip-visible")`

Comment: unfortunately not resloving my problem

Comment: It wasn't meant to, otherwise I would post it as an aswer. I was just pointing out an issue with your code.

Comment: are you just trying to make a gallery?

Comment: yes something like this.

Comment: Your `<div` is missing its `">`

Comment: And please update your question with the corrected code from comments, so other people don't have to spend time on those errors (unless it fixes the problem, then leave it for the answers)

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of little errors in your code.

HTML: `class="imp-tooltip.imp-tooltip-visible"`
Should be: `class="imp-tooltip imp-tooltip-visible"`

JS: `$(".imp-tooltip imp-tooltip-visible").first()`
Should be: `$(".imp-tooltip-visible").first()`

What is the purpose of the `imp-tooltip-visible` class? Is it there to indicate what is currently the active element? If so, then you forgot to remove this class from `$currentElement` before assigning a new element to it. And after performing this operation this class should be added to the new `$currentElement`. This would also make the `.first()` part in the selector redundant since there should only be one element with this class.
If on the other hand this class indicates which imp-tooltip divs are actually visibly available, then the `next()` and `prev()` functions should be targeting `imp-tooltip-visible` instead of `imp-tooltip`.